# NEXT JS 13 'use client' gives unexpected error

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using the **experimental app directory** with **TypeScript support.**

This is a **Server** component.

```
export default function SimpleComponent() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Now I want to introduce **state** here. So logically I would have to turn this into a **Client component** by using the **'use client'** directive. Right?

OK. So I turned it into a simple client component with state.

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function SimpleComponent() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("Simple Client Component");

  function handleClick() {
    setWord("Hello");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 onClick={handleClick}>{word}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I do this, I get this error in my terminal.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()

[image]

And the webpage turns white. wait I'll show you!

[image]

1. I don't understand what is the error.
2. I saw other blogs and youtubers doing the exact same thing. And their code works.
3. I tried to run this code in Code Sandbox instead of VS Code. And it worked in Code Sandbox!
   Here's the link - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/divine-currying-1902zv?file=%2FREADME.md

So, I must be doing something really stupid here. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'd be thankful if you could help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, it was related to the next version specified in package.json
Try replacing your Next version in your package.json to 13.1.1:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "13.1.1",
}
```

After that, remove package.lock.json file, and .next, node_modules folders. Then reinstall again:

```
npm i

npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the official NEXT JS Github Page.

One of them told me to convert my `normal function` into an `arrow function`

So all I had to do was change this

```
export default function SimpleComponent() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("Simple Client Component");

  function handleClick() {
    setWord("Hello");
  }

 return (
    <>
      <h1 onClick={handleClick}>{word}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

into this

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'

const SimpleComponent:NextPage = () => {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("Simple Client Component");

  function handleClick() {
    setWord("Hello");
  }

 return (
    <>
      <h1 onClick={handleClick}>{word}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default SimpleComponent
```

I tried this solution and it worked!